# Apple Magic Mouse 2 in Arch Linux - Keeps Disconnecting

Tags: linux, bluetooth, magic-mouse

I've a second generation apple magic mouse 2 that works perfectly on my macbook pro. When I connect it to my linux machine however, which is running Antergos / Arch Linux, the mouse just disconnects as soon as its paired. Then it disconnects as soon as I try to connect it again.

Not sure how to fix this. Anyone have any idea how to prevent the mouse from disconnecting so that it can actually be used?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changed beyond an upgrade to the kernel, so I think there is a very good chance that this might be a way to fix it. If yer having this problem, try to upgrade the linux kernel to a more recent one, 4.13.12-1-ARCH definitely works for me.